# c++ Outputs One Too Many Times

Tags: c++, do-while

I am making a program that outputs an increasing integer until it reaches 400. Even when less than 400 in for "while" is added, it always goes over once. Any Suggestions to fix?

```
cout << "enter population of US at end of last year (in millions): ";
cin >> USpop;



do {
    USpop = USpop * 1.01007;
    year = year +1;
    cout<< "  " << year  << "  " << setprecision(1) << fixed << USpop <<endl;

} while (USpop < 400);
```

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Reduce `400` temporarily to e.g. `3` and watch this while debugging step-wise. Please, recall the difference between `while () { }` and `do { } while ()`. (This is subject of any programming base course, not only for C++.)

Comment: Thank you! even as a while () { } loop, it goes over by one. is there a command to ignore the last output since it is technically false?

Comment: Put a if condition checking greater then 400 just before cout. OR use while() {}, pre-condition check in this will avoid the last greater then 400 output.

Comment: Change the do-while loop to a regular while loop, specifically `while ((USpop *= 1.01007) < 400) { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this?

```
while((USpop *= 1.01007) < 400)
{
    year = year + 1;
    cout << "  " << year << "  " << fixed << USpop << endl;
}
```